# Algebraists' Intuition on Center and Centralizer

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I would like to ask of some intuitive ways which algebraists use to picture the centers, centralizers and their relation.

I understand that the center is the intersection of all centralizers. But this doesn't really help me if I cannot picture the centers and the centralizers individually.

Any other hint or an intuitive window through which I can see the two would be helpful I guess. Thanks.